# How to know cookies are enabled or not in any browser?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to know about cookies are enabled in browser in javascript by using below code. but even i disable the cookies in browser. its showing enabled. Can any one help to how to know about cookies are enabled or not in browser.

Used Code snippet:

```
    var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false 
//if not IE4+ nor NS6+
if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
    alert('cookies are not enabled');
    document.cookie="testcookie"
    cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false 
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try this: http://sveinbjorn.org/cookiecheck

Comment: navigator.coockieEnabled should work well for modern browser. have you considered to use a micro lib? http://microjs.com/#cookies

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var supportsCookies = checkCookie();

function checkCookie(){
    var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false   
    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled)?true:false;
}
```

Also, please search google before asking questions on SO.

Browsers I have checked:

```
 ________________
| Safari  | True |
| Chrome  | True |
******************
```

Comment: I tried this one but it's not working in Internet Explorer( version 8). Even i block the cookies also it's returning true value.

Comment: @VenkatVemula Strange, try this one…